# madvise failed when trying to offline the ram pages

Tags: linux, memory-management

I had the line below in my code

```
madvise(address, size, MADV_SOFT_OFFLINE);
```

The address is page aliged and the size is two pages. I test the return value, and find it failed and the perror shows

```
Operation not permitted!
```

My system is linux x86_64 3.2.0. Any clue?

Comment: Read `madvise(2)` man page. Have you configured your kernel with `CONFIG_MEMORY_FAILURE`? Do you have ECC RAM ?

Comment: Thanks Basile. I have ECC RAM and the kernel config file shows that `CONFIG_MEMORY_FAILURE` is enabled. After several tries, I find more info. If I invoke `mprotect(address, size, PROT_NONE)` before calling `madvise`, it always fails. Otherwise, it can succeed (only) with root user.